# How can I heal a burnt tongue?

Tags: personal-care, comfort

A lot of times, when I have some super nice food in front of me, I eat rather fast, without waiting for it to cool down, thus burning my tongue.

**How can I heal this kind of burn?**

Comment: To be clear, are you looking for an actual cure, or just something to soothe the pain?

Comment: @MattS. both of them

Comment: Can't you just drink water?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What can help the pain to disappear? Something cooling. So breathe through the mouth, eat something cold, e.g. youghurt. Or drink some cold water. Or Coca Cola :)

Also, as [wikihow.com states](http://wikihow.com/Soothe-a-Burnt-Tongue), you can try:

1. Sucking an ice cube
2. Sprinkling powder sugar on your tongue.
3. Eating a spoon of honey
4. Opening a 1,000 IU Vitamin E capsule and spreading the oil on the burnt part of your tongue.
5. Putting a little Aloe Vera gel (directly from the plant) on the burnt part of your tongue.

Comment: Be wary of sucking icecubes though. I know I get strong temptations to chew the ice, but this damages your teeth (source: my dentist said this)